# PHP or C#.Net based ticketing system

Tags: web-apps, support-tracker

We look for a PHP or C#.Net based ticketing system. It should be possible to host it on our own.

It should be easy to use and localised in German.

The purpose is to give our customers a tool to submit tickets easily to the support. It should be possible to get some kind of statistics/reports.

The most important requirment is that we can host it on our own.

Requirements:

- localisation in German
- custom fields (one or two additional fields beside the required category per ticket)
- priorities
- modern/state of the art UI
- statistic regarding average agent response time
- available to be self hosted (no SaaS)
- screenshot attachments

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and include which features you are requiring? E.g. customizable fields, attachment handling, workflow, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I just found one on my own. It pretty much covers all requirements.

http://www.jitbit.com/web-helpdesk/

- Many localisations
- Available as self hosted application for IIS (ASP.net MVC Web Application)
- Pricing: http://www.jitbit.com/web-helpdesk/purchase/
- (also available as Saas)
- Allows to define mutliple custom fields (different types also select boxes)
- Convinient Access Rights: Public or registered users only for ticket submission. Public register page can be disabled too.
- Attachments
- Modern looking statistics
- Additional free aps for iOS and android
- Modern looking UI in general (not responsive but you have the free apps)
- Priorities
- Comprehensive API
- Worklows: Automation rules

Other systems can be found here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/top-support-ticket-systems/